# Testing for class field with is share among methods

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I have a Java class as follow

```
public class MyClass {
    private final ShowFactory showFactory;
    private SomeShow someShow;

    public MyClass(ShowFactory showFactory) {
        this.showFactory = showFactory;
        startShow();
    }

    public void startShow() {
        someShow = showFactory.createShow();
        someShow.start();
    }

    public void showSomething() {
        MagicBox magicBox = new MagicBox();
        someShow.showSomething(magicBox);
    }

    public void stopShow() {
        someShow.stop();
    }
}
```

and trying to test `showSomething` method. Complete test file is as follow

```
public class MyClassTest {
    private ShowFactory showFactory;
    private SomeShow someShow;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        showFactory = mock(ShowFactory.class);
        someShow = mock(SomeShow.class);

        when(showFactory.createShow()).thenReturn(someShow);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldStartShow() {
        new MyClass(showFactory);

        verify(someShow).start();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldShowSomething() throws Exception {
        MagicBox magicBox = mock(MagicBox.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(MagicBox.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(magicBox);
        doNothing().when(someShow).showSomething(magicBox);
        InOrder inOrder = inOrder(someShow);

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(showFactory);
        myClass.showSomething();

        inOrder.verify(someShow).start();
        inOrder.verify(someShow).showSomething(magicBox);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldStopShow() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(showFactory);
        myClass.stopShow();

        verify(someShow).start();
        verify(someShow).stop();
    }
}
```

But test `shouldShowSomething` is failing with error `Wanted but not invoked`. Any thing I am missing here? Any suggestion?

Comment: I think you need a few more steps to use `PowerMockito.whenNew` to mock a constructor call https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor#quick-summary

So it needs to be run with PowerMockRunner and use an @PrepareForTest with the right class in it.

Mocking the internals of the method down to constructor call is pretty deep. Could you alternately use matchers to assert that the `magicBox` is in a desirable state? Like `inOrder.verify(someShow).showSomething(argThat(argument -> matchingLogicGoesHere));`.

Answer (score 0):

It was simple fix. After reading through https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor#quick-summary (thanks to @roby) turns out I was missing the `@PrepareForTest` annotation for the class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class MyClassTest {
 ...
}
```